# Many database calls, or a single large call?

Tags: database, postgresql

## Database setup

I have a PostgreSQL database with tables **posts** and **comments** that are on posts.

These tables have columns,

**posts**:
postid, body

**comments**:
commentid, postid*, body

(obviously **comments**.postid references **posts**.postid)

## Problem

I want my server to fetch from the database a post, and the first 10 comments on that post, given a `POSTID`.

There are two ways of calling the database

#### 1) using one large call

The call would look something like

```
select * from posts
where postid = POSTID

join

select * from comments
where comments have POSTID
```

**Cons:**

There is redundant data, since the column `postid` will be returned for every entry. We want it returned only once.

Also, I think doing a single call means the database has to run a sequence of events (not in parallel, which is slower)

#### 2) using two smaller calls

The calls would be

```
select * from posts
where postid = POSTID
```

and then

```
select * from comments
where postid = POSTID
```

**Cons:** Doing many calls means many back and forths between server and database.

## Which of these approaches is best practice?

I am asking about a toy model, but the answer applies if you have replies inside of comments, or more complicated structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a single call will always be better, there are exceptions but those are rare especially when you also consider network latency. Further, each call has its own *sequence of events*. Your complaint of *redundant data* holds true for your multiple call as well.   
So a single call will be better. But the way you structured it is incorrect. I am not sure whether you mean the `postid` is redundant across a row or within a row. You eliminate within row redundancy by specifying the columns you want (abandon select *). You eliminate across row redundancy in your apps presentation manager.

```
select p.pastid, p.body, c.commentid, c.body
  from posts p 
  left join comments c 
    on c.postid = p.postid
 order by p.postid, c.commentid 
 limit 10;
```

Note: the `left join` allows for the inclusion of `posts` that have no comments. If that is not desirable then just use `join comments ...` (i.e. an inner join).

Comment: How does that remove redundancy? Each row in the returned table will have a postid. And since we have many comments, all with the same postid, all these postids will be the same. Is there a way to avoid this redundancy or am I missing something?

Comment: It removes the redundancy within a row, i.e a row will contain postid once. Using `select *` gives the same postid  several times in a single row, once for each table. Having the same postid on different rows is not redundant as that is the definition of the row. (You could eliminate even that, but you essentially have the other columns into an array. To contain different data types requires creating a UDT). SQL does not have `merge cells` like a spreadsheet does, strictly haw data is displayed. That is something for your apps presentation manager to handle.

Comment: But what if I have comments and replies on those comments? Then we return something like | postid | commentid | replyid |. postid will be the same for every entry, which is highly redundant. And commentid will also be very redundant. Maybe this is how they are defined, but in no world is this “not redundant”. Is this redundancy normal/ negligible/ is it normal to do things the way I’m doing them?